# Converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone please tell me what 's wrong with this code that I get error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
, iif(t1.medbuildcmpltdt IS NOT NULL,cast(datediff(day, t1.medbuildcmpltdt,t1.orderingtoolbuildcmpltdt)AS nvarchar(255)), cast(t1.orderingtoolbuildcmpltdt AS nvarchar(255)) AS 'Main_Days Build'
```

Comment: Could you double check the data type of these two columns?: t1.medbuildcmpltdt & t1.orderingtoolbuildcmpltdt

Comment: @Gen Wan, both of them are date

Comment: We don't have access to your data, so can't run or replicate this problem. This sounds like you're storing `orderingtoolbuildcmpltdt` as a datatype other than a date and time data type, and hence the error. Using the correct data type is important.

Comment: Also, you're missing a closing parenthesis. If you fix that, however, those 2 columns being a `date` does **not** replicate the error: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6cfcbe738a3403fb5e987006afae3923)

Comment: Does your query work if you comment out that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The problem is where SQL Server wants a date or datetime and is receiving a string.  The only thing in the code you provided that requires a date or datetime is

```
datediff(
    day, 
    t1.medbuildcmpltdt, 
    t1.orderingtoolbuildcmpltdt
)
```

So, t1.medbuildcmpltdt or t1.orderingtoolbuildcmpltdt is a string ([n][var]char) and contains values that cannot be interpreted as valid date or datetime values.